# How to add image file in folder after get src image crawler into website?

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, web-crawler

I want to add image file into the folder in Codeigniter.

I using library DOMXpath to get data image from the website. I have function: `getNew()`: to get list image.

Problem is:

I get an URL of image success.

I want to save this image to a folder in my server with the custom name of a folder.
Don't dependency URL was a crawler.

Ex:
Before: `http://example.com/2017-3-22/picture.png`

It should save into my server with a name like that:

After: `http://my-website.com/upload/newimg/picture.png`

My code :

```
function getNew(){
     $xpath_thumb = //*[@id='news_home']/li/div/div[1]/a/img;
     $cateWebsite = 'http://vnexpress.net/tin-tuc/thoi-su';
     $doc = new DOMDocument();
     $internalErrors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
     $loadHtml = $doc->loadHTMLfile($cateWebsite);
     if($loadHtml){
       $xpath   = new DOMXpath($doc);
       $thumb   = $xpath->query($xpath_thumb);
       $result  = array();
       for ($i=0; $i < $title->length; $i++) {
          $result[$i]['thumb']= $thumb[$i]->getAttribute('src');
       }
     }
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: what doesn't work? I don't understand